# Trace and change of basis for measurement

Tags: measurement

Let $|\psi\rangle$ be a state vector for a quantum state that is a linear combination of $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$.

In density matrix, the state vector can be described by $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$.

The probability associated with measurement outcome $|0 \rangle$: $Tr[M_{0}^{\dagger} M_{0}\rho]$.

The probability associated with measurement outcome $|1 \rangle$: $Tr[M_{1}^{\dagger} M_{1}\rho]$

Suppose we wish to perform a new measurement under the new basis $|v_{0}\rangle, |v_{1}\rangle$ such that $|v_{0}\rangle = U|0\rangle, |v_{1}\rangle = U|1\rangle$.

The probability that the measurement on the quantum state, described by density matrix $\rho$, has measurement outcome $|0\rangle$: $Tr[\rho |v_{0}\rangle \langle v_{0}|]$.

The probability that the measurement on the quantum state, described by density matrix $\rho$, has measurement outcome $|1\rangle$: $Tr[\rho |v_{1}\rangle \langle v_{1}|]$.

As can be seen, the position of the density matrix and the measurement matrix has been swapped. Why is this?

Comment: Cyclic property of trace: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property